FastAPI/Poetry Docker Deployment on Digital Ocean App Platform/Droplet
I have a FastAPI Project  that I am trying to deploy on Digital Ocean's App Platform. I am using a base CPU instance, which is not the issue because I have tested on larger images with more RAM and CPUs.
I have a Dockerfile for my FastAPI app, that builds and runs successfully on my local machine (MacBook Pro M3 Pro), but when I attmept to deploy via Github/Dockerfile on the App Platform I keep getting two errors:
Deploy Error: Container Terminated & Deploy Error: Health Checks
There seems to be an issue when the Docker container spins up in that my project is not installed properly or referenced correctly, becuase when I want to use any modules that import components form the package itself (i.e humblapi.core.config import Config) the container seems to hang. It seems the conaitner will deploy successfully if I just have one file as my FastAPI app, but not when importing modules form the package. I have seen an error message that the humblapi package was not installed (when I wasn't using --no-root) and also /app/src/humblapi does not contain any element.
How do I get poetry to install properly or get my container to run?
Attempts
I have tried using poetry install --no-root to avoid installing the package itself, which hasn't worked.
I have tried changing the [tool.poetry] to include packages = [{ include = "humblapi", from = "src" },], this did not work.
I have tried doing the suggested pip install from FastAPI docs, that didn't work.
The deployment is only successful when I do not include any humblapi imports.
I have also deployed a droplet, with the pip-install branch from humblAPI and I am also met with a hanging container. It seems that it only runs on my local machine. What is causing this?
Do you know if I can only use relative imports for Digital Ocean? I am confused because my local Dockerfile container runs perfectly.
The lastest attempt of trying to deploy the pip-install` branch has this error. It starts up, but then collapses and quits.

Resources
I am using docker build -t humblapi . & docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 humblapi
poetry install --no-root (runs locally)
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    curl \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    libsoup2.4-dev \
    libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev \
    libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Rust
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

# Copy project files
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* README.md /app/

# Install dependencies without pywry
RUN pip install poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root -v

# Install pywry separately
RUN pip install pywry==0.6.2

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["fastapi", "run", "src/humblapi/main.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]

pip install multi-stage Dockerfile (runs locally)
# Stage 1: Generate requirements.txt
FROM python:3.11-slim as requirements-stage

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /tmp/

RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes

# Stage 2: Final image
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    curl \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    libsoup2.4-dev \
    libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev \
    libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Rust
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

# Copy requirements.txt from the previous stage
COPY --from=requirements-stage /tmp/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["fastapi", "run", "src/humblapi/main.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]

ARNE SOLUTION ERROR
I have added
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

and I still get this error:
 docker build --no-cache -t humblapi:develop-new .

[+] Building 95.3s (18/22)                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s

...


48.91 Saved ./wheels/wrapt-1.16.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
48.91 Saved ./wheels/xmltodict-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
48.91 Saved ./wheels/yarl-1.9.4-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
48.91 Saved ./wheels/yfinance-0.2.40-py2.py3-none-any.whl
48.91 Saved ./wheels/zipp-3.19.2-py3-none-any.whl
48.91 Saved ./wheels/zope.interface-6.4.post2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl
48.91 Building wheels for collected packages: linearmodels, pandas-ta, peewee, pywry
48.91   Building wheel for linearmodels (pyproject.toml): started
53.91   Building wheel for linearmodels (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
53.91   Created wheel for linearmodels: filename=linearmodels-4.25-cp311-cp311-linux_aarch64.whl size=1921643 sha256=8d8b3807ebee1482ca197d7b04e7e90c11d99971bddf6a9174329f3d6ccec372
53.91   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/bb/c1/c4/889e7eff2dbf726c41e207c98a23eb8f82e34a1315af53df98
53.91   Building wheel for pandas-ta (pyproject.toml): started
54.02   Building wheel for pandas-ta (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
54.02   Created wheel for pandas-ta: filename=pandas_ta-0.3.14b0-py3-none-any.whl size=218910 sha256=6a9ea14430f4ec8e8dacd1711a16f3ca2d81e5dbbedaf65dfd36e67040a373cb
54.02   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7f/33/8b/50b245c5c65433cd8f5cb24ac15d97e5a3db2d41a8b6ae957d
54.02   Building wheel for peewee (pyproject.toml): started
58.27   Building wheel for peewee (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
58.27   Created wheel for peewee: filename=peewee-3.17.6-cp311-cp311-linux_aarch64.whl size=876729 sha256=0c2ca67489e3a434a972ad3a06960aace503f88352ccdaf7b08ffd1c5042739e
58.27   Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/1c/09/7e/9f659fde248ecdc1722a142c1d744271aad3914a0afc191058
58.27   Building wheel for pywry (pyproject.toml): started
62.37   Building wheel for pywry (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
62.37   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
62.37
62.37   × Building wheel for pywry (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
62.37   │ exit code: 1
62.37   ╰─> [119 lines of output]
62.37       Running `maturin pep517 build-wheel -i /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/humblapi-XDF0t07c-py3.11/bin/python --compatibility off`
62.37       ⚠️  Warning: Please use maturin in pyproject.toml with a version constraint, e.g. `requires = ["maturin>=1.0,<2.0"]`. This will become an error.
62.37        Including license file "/tmp/pip-wheel-r6hbeiv5/pywry_672648706bc1479f91b19d671ff14b04/LICENSE"
62.37        Building a mixed python/rust project
62.37        Found bin bindings
62.37          Compiling serde v1.0.189
62.37          Compiling pkg-config v0.3.27
62.37          Compiling smallvec v1.10.0
62.37          Compiling hashbrown v0.14.0
62.37          Compiling equivalent v1.0.1
62.37          Compiling winnow v0.5.15
62.37          Compiling target-lexicon v0.12.11
62.37          Compiling heck v0.4.1
62.37          Compiling version-compare v0.1.1
62.37          Compiling libc v0.2.149
62.37          Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
62.37          Compiling version_check v0.9.4
62.37          Compiling indexmap v2.0.0
62.37          Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.67
62.37          Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.8
62.37          Compiling cfg-expr v0.15.5
62.37          Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
62.37          Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
62.37          Compiling futures-core v0.3.28
62.37          Compiling syn v1.0.109
62.37          Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
62.37          Compiling slab v0.4.9
62.37          Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
62.37          Compiling anyhow v1.0.75
62.37          Compiling once_cell v1.17.1
62.37          Compiling futures-task v0.3.28
62.37          Compiling quote v1.0.33
62.37          Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.13
62.37          Compiling futures-util v0.3.28
62.37          Compiling syn v2.0.36
62.37          Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
62.37          Compiling thiserror v1.0.48
62.37          Compiling unicode-segmentation v1.10.1
62.37          Compiling futures-channel v0.3.28
62.37          Compiling cfg-expr v0.9.1
62.37          Compiling version-compare v0.0.11
62.37          Compiling semver v1.0.18
62.37          Compiling heck v0.3.3
62.37          Compiling gio v0.15.12
62.37          Compiling futures-io v0.3.28
62.37          Compiling unicase v2.6.0
62.37          Compiling memoffset v0.9.0
62.37          Compiling simd-adler32 v0.3.5
62.37          Compiling rustc_version v0.4.0
62.37          Compiling crc32fast v1.3.2
62.37          Compiling getrandom v0.2.9
62.37          Compiling lock_api v0.4.9
62.37          Compiling field-offset v0.3.6
62.37          Compiling log v0.4.17
62.37          Compiling adler v1.0.2
62.37          Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.8
62.37          Compiling miniz_oxide v0.7.1
62.37          Compiling gtk v0.15.5
62.37          Compiling x11 v2.21.0
62.37          Compiling num-traits v0.2.15
62.37          Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.8.16
62.37          Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
62.37          Compiling serde_spanned v0.6.3
62.37          Compiling toml_datetime v0.6.3
62.37          Compiling toml v0.5.11
62.37          Compiling tinyvec_macros v0.1.1
62.37          Compiling tinyvec v1.6.0
62.37          Compiling toml_edit v0.19.15
62.37          Compiling cc v1.0.83
62.37          Compiling system-deps v5.0.0
62.37          Compiling futures-executor v0.3.28
62.37          Compiling flate2 v1.0.26
62.37          Compiling fdeflate v0.3.0
62.37          Compiling toml v0.7.8
62.37          Compiling proc-macro-crate v1.3.1
62.37          Compiling soup2-sys v0.2.0
62.37          Compiling javascriptcore-rs-sys v0.4.0
62.37          Compiling system-deps v6.1.1
62.37       The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
62.37
62.37       warning: soup2-sys@0.2.0: `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "libsoup-2.4" "libsoup-2.4 >= 2.62"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
62.37
62.37       error: failed to run custom build command for `soup2-sys v0.2.0`
62.37
62.37       Caused by:
62.37         process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/pip-wheel-r6hbeiv5/pywry_672648706bc1479f91b19d671ff14b04/target/release/build/soup2-sys-4953b3cc1053678a/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
62.37         --- stdout
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBSOUP_2.4_NO_PKG_CONFIG
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
62.37         cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
62.37         cargo:warning=`PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "libsoup-2.4" "libsoup-2.4 >= 2.62"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
62.37         error: could not find system library 'libsoup-2.4' required by the 'soup2-sys' crate
62.37
62.37         --- stderr
62.37         Package libsoup-2.4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
62.37         Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libsoup-2.4.pc'
62.37         to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
62.37         Package 'libsoup-2.4', required by 'virtual:world', not found
62.37         Package 'libsoup-2.4', required by 'virtual:world', not found
62.37
62.37       warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
62.37        maturin failed
62.37         Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo
62.37         Caused by: Cargo build finished with "exit status: 101": `env -u CARGO "cargo" "rustc" "--message-format" "json-render-diagnostics" "--manifest-path" "/tmp/pip-wheel-r6hbeiv5/pywry_672648706bc1479f91b19d671ff14b04/Cargo.toml" "--release" "--bin" "pywry"`
62.37       Error: command ['maturin', 'pep517', 'build-wheel', '-i', '/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/humblapi-XDF0t07c-py3.11/bin/python', '--compatibility', 'off'] returned non-zero exit status 1
62.37       [end of output]
62.37
62.37   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
62.37   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pywry
62.37 Successfully built linearmodels pandas-ta peewee
62.37 Failed to build pywry
62.37 ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
62.38
62.38 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.1 -> 24.1.2
62.38 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
Dockerfile:21
--------------------
  19 |     RUN poetry build -f wheel
  20 |     RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes
  21 | >>> RUN poetry run pip wheel -w wheels -r requirements.txt
  22 |     RUN mv dist/* wheels
  23 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c poetry run pip wheel -w wheels -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/nxmnfopdykkadaxass0212qo2

If i use this Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11 as build

WORKDIR /build

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    libsoup2.4-dev \
    libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev \
    libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install poetry and add it to PATH
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"


COPY src src
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* README.md ./

RUN poetry build -f wheel
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes
RUN poetry run pip wheel -w wheels -r requirements.txt
RUN mv dist/* wheels

FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Copy dependencies from the previous stage
COPY --from=build /build/wheels /app/wheels

# Set up a virtual environment
RUN python -m venv venv

# Install dependencies
# RUN venv/bin/pip install "uvicorn[standard]"  # TODO: run `poetry add` on me instead
RUN venv/bin/pip install wheels/* --no-deps --no-index

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["venv/bin/uvicorn", "humblapi.main:app"]
CMD ["--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]

then it builds successfully (locally)

yeah, it's an import issue. The important distinction between approaches is whether you want poetry to manage your venv in the container which ends up running your app or not. Do you have a preference?

At first I wanted to use poetry, because I like its package resolution and env management, but to make a leaner image and not have all of poetry and its dependencies, I prefer the pip install.
This keeps the base image lighter and poetry can be used during development, and just create requirements each build to install.

ok, I got around to test the image from my post. does it work for you too?

no it doesn't. I am getting erros when installing/building the wheel for  pywry

It seems removing the system dependencies results in an error when building the wheel. @Arne

Please see solution comments in the OP

You can get either approach you chose in your Dockerfiles to work, but for brevity's sake I'll only address the one with a dedicated build-stage and no poetry in the deployed image, because

I personally prefer it
OP seems to prefer it, too
it lets you separate build-requirements from runtime-requirements, which makes a lot of sense if you want to use any *-slim kind of docker image as your base

how to avoid import errors in python
You could fill paragraphs on this issue alone, but the most common conclusion, this issue included, is "install your code as a package". The fastapi docs don't suggest it, but as soon as you have more than one file, you should just install them. The good news is that since you're using poetry, you avoid 90% of the usual problems and can just run poetry build to get a distribution of your code.
You do need to switch from fastapi run to boot your application to uvicorn, since fastapi run only supports file paths to find your application, and no package/module paths.
I installed uvicorn with pip in the prod-image, but you should probably use poetry add "uvicorn[standard]" to get it into your application.
poetry shouldn't be installed with pip
See here why, with an example of how to set up a docker image.
entrypoint vs cmd
Just a detail, but splitting the startup-command in this way you can configure things a bit more easily. See here for more details.
don't including build-dependencies in prod
I don't know your backend good enough to guess which of your dependencies are runtime and which are build-time. But now that you can isolate the build-environment, you got a chance to cut down heavily on your final image-size.
I just got rid of all of them and things still seemed to work just fine, but I also don't know what you're still planning to add.
export a wheelhouse, not a requirements.txt
Separating build and prod only makes sense if you're actually done building after the build stage, so the command that turns your lockfile into the corresponding wheels needs to take place within the build-stage. The result is commonly called a wheelhouse, which is what the prod-stage will copy over and install with a pip install [...] --no-deps --no-index to exclude the possibility that anything else but the content of the wheelhouse is getting installed.

The working Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11 as build

WORKDIR /build

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gcc

# Install poetry and add it to PATH
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

COPY src src
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* README.md ./

RUN poetry build -f wheel
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes
RUN poetry run pip wheel -w wheels -r requirements.txt
RUN mv dist/* wheels

FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Copy dependencies from the previous stage
COPY --from=build /build/wheels /app/wheels

# Set up a virtual environment
RUN python -m venv venv

# Install dependencies
RUN venv/bin/pip install "uvicorn[standard]"  # TODO: run `poetry add` on me instead
RUN venv/bin/pip install wheels/* --no-deps --no-index

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["venv/bin/uvicorn", "humblapi.main:app"]
CMD ["--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]


I get an error when I build that docker image you suggested:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
20.73   │ exit code: 1
20.73   ╰─> [6 lines of output]
20.73
20.73       Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
20.73       This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
20.73       the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
20.73
20.73       Checking for Rust toolchain....
20.73       [end of output]

I can include the build-dependencies in the build stage and remove them from prod stage, but I can't get it to build removing them from both stages.

Another option is to just install deps in a virtualenv in the build-time container and then copy over the virtualenv (into the exact same location!) into the runtime container.

@AKX I wouldn't recommend it since, as you said, it needs to be in the exact same path as it was in the build system. virtual envs hard-code their internal links, so copying them in any shape or form is playing with fire. Installing a wheelhouse is essentially just a copy statement plus metadata generation, so it is always very fast, and ensures that metadata and links always work. I'd always opt for wheelhouses as build artifacts over a finished virtual env.

@JJFantini Interesting, I checked out your master branch and for me the build just works with this Dockerfile. I wonder how a docker build can work on one system and not on another..

@Arne It should be perfectly OK to do python -m venv /venv in the first container and COPY --from=build /venv /venv. Occasionally it works better/faster than the wheelhouse approach, with which I'm also very familiar with.  (See this discussion :))

Yeah i know, that is odd, docker is supposed to solve the isolation of ends...not amek them. I wonder why the system deps arent needed in your case? I think they are needed for openbb package.
